# Selenium error name is not defined PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, python-re

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

ser = Service("C:\\Users\\czoca\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject4\\chromedriver.exe")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=op)
s.get('https://autosalpa.fi/fi/')

EMAIL_REGEX = r'''(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'''

list_of_emails = []

for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, page_source):
    list_of_emails.append(re_match.group())

for i, email in enumerate(list_of_emails):
    print(f'{i+1}:{email}')
```

This is my code and the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\czoca\PycharmProjects\imagesscraping\main.py", line 14, in <module>
for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, page_source):
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

NameError: name 'page_source' is not defined

I am not sure what is wrong here..

Comment: i found out, sorry ignore

Comment: Hi, can you post how was solved?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work.
In Selenium 4 you don't have to download the webdriver, you just need to import the webdriver of the browser you use.
the necessary steps to use Selenium 4 with python are explained  [here](https://github.com/MarouaNoui/SeleniumTesting/blob/main/Installing%20and%20configuring%20Selenium%20with%20python.pdf)

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://autosalpa.fi/fi/')

EMAIL_REGEX = r'''(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])'''
page_source=driver.page_source
list_of_emails = []

for re_match in re.finditer(EMAIL_REGEX, page_source):
    list_of_emails.append(re_match.group())

for i, email in enumerate(list_of_emails):
    print(f'{i+1}:{email}')
```